# Nameservers are unresponsive, can't start named

Tags: linux, centos, nameserver, service

I've tried restarting them

```
# /sbin/service named restart
Stopping named: [ OK ]
Starting named: [FAILED]
```

And I've tried this to fix it

```
# yum install dbus
```

Which completed successfully. But I still can't get them to start.

---

Some useful information

```
[root@ip-184-168-86-185 /]# /sbin/service named restart
Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named:                                            [FAILED]
[root@ip-184-168-86-185 /]# tail -50 /var/log/messages
2011-09-20T18:32:37.322626-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="3.22.1" x-pid="3127" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
2011-09-20T18:32:37.321006-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 rsyslogd: WARNING: rsyslogd is running in compatibility mode. Automatically generated config directives may interfer with your rsyslog.conf settings. We suggest upgrading your config and adding -c3 as the first rsyslogd option.
2011-09-20T18:32:37.322354-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 rsyslogd: Warning: backward compatibility layer added to following directive to rsyslog.conf: ModLoad imuxsock
2011-09-21T11:38:21.437308-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 shutdown[16303]: shutting down for system reboot
2011-09-21T11:38:22.551115-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 init: Switching to runlevel: 6
2011-09-21T11:38:22.578505-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 saslauthd[1834]: server_exit     : master exited: 1834
2011-09-21T11:38:38.059150-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 xinetd[1422]: Exiting...
```

-

```
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      381956 Feb 22  2011 named
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        7299 Feb 22  2011 named-bootconf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       13640 Feb 22  2011 named-checkconf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       13644 Feb 22  2011 named-checkzone
```

-

```
[root@ip-184-168-86-185 /]# grep named /var/log/messages
[root@ip-184-168-86-185 /]# ls -la /etc/named.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root named 32 Feb  1  2011 /etc/named.conf -> /var/named-chroot/etc/named.conf
[root@ip-184-168-86-185 /]# ls -la /etc/rndc.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root named 32 May 23 16:23 /etc/rndc.conf -> /var/named-chroot//etc/rndc.conf
[root@ip-184-168-86-185 /]# nano etc/named.conf
options {
        directory "/var/named";
        /*
         * If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
         * to talk to, you might need to uncomment the query-source
         * directive below.  Previous versions of BIND always asked
         * questions using port 53, but BIND 8.1 uses an unprivileged
         * port by default.
         */
        // query-source address * port 53;

        // don't allow queries for domains we don't know about
        allow-recursion {localnets; };
};

controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { rndckey; };
};
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.root";
};

zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "forward.localhost";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "reverse.127.0.0";
        allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/rndc.key";

include "/etc/named-turbopanel.conf";
```

Comment: You need to provide more details here. Log excerpts, troubleshooting steps, etc.

Comment: Usually, you will see the error in /var/log/message. What does it say there? Do this if you can't find it:

/sbin/service named restart ; tail -50 /var/log/messages

Then update the post with the output.

Comment: I've added the log data

Comment: Wait, init 6? it sound like it still in the process of rebooting:

Do: 

grep named /var/log/messages.

And do a ls -la on the following:

ls -la /etc/named.conf
ls -la /etc/rndc.conf

Copy and past the output as well as the content of named.conf.

Comment: Done and added.

Comment: See my note. We may still need to view the permissions, but it doesn't look like a named issue at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your last output.

```
2011-09-20T18:32:37.322626-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="3.22.1" x-pid="3127" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
2011-09-20T18:32:37.321006-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 rsyslogd: WARNING: rsyslogd is running in compatibility mode. Automatically generated config directives may interfer with your rsyslog.conf settings. We suggest upgrading your config and adding -c3 as the first rsyslogd option.
2011-09-20T18:32:37.322354-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 rsyslogd: Warning: backward compatibility layer added to following directive to rsyslog.conf: ModLoad imuxsock
2011-09-21T11:38:21.437308-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 shutdown[16303]: shutting down for system reboot
2011-09-21T11:38:22.551115-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 init: Switching to runlevel: 6
2011-09-21T11:38:22.578505-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 saslauthd[1834]: server_exit     : master exited: 1834
2011-09-21T11:38:38.059150-07:00 ip-184-168-86-185 xinetd[1422]: Exiting...
```

it seems like the server is in process of restarting, but hung for some reason. Do a:

```
init 3
```

or restart the server. (most likely you may end up doing that anyway).

EDIT: Looks like there is a permission problem:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root  5572 Sep 21 12:55 named-turbopanel.conf
```

Apparently that was added today, which is why you couldn't restart named properly - named could not read it.

Change the owernship:

```
chown root:named named-turbopanel.conf
```

and give it read permissions to :

```
chmod 644 named-turbopanel.conf
```

Incidentally, since you are running cents, check to see if you are running SELinux. If you are seeing the following output:

```
[root@localhost etc]# getenforce
Enforcing
```

Then you need the give it the following ACLs:

```
chcon -u system_u -t named_conf_t named-turbopanel.conf
```

and then make sure to label it correctly:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t named_conf_t named-turbopanel.conf
```

If you don't have semanage,  you will need to install it via the policycoreutils-python.

Comment: Tried all that.  Still not working http://pastebin.com/UsxMLSCc

Comment: Okay, let's try a tail -50 /var/log/messages, now that reboot condition clear

Comment: And please get the ls -la output of the following: /etc/named.conf, /etc/rndc.key and /etc/named-turbopanel.conf

Comment: No turbopanel but here's the rest.  Looks like it's still on 6 http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=J3cynGMJ

Comment: Run "uptime" If it is more than a few minutes, the server didn't reboot. If this is a VPS of some sort, try to see if you can reboot it from your control panel.

Comment: meanwhile, since this is a chroot account, do ls -la on the directory /var/named-chroot/etc/

Comment: The reboot took. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AFB4vbsS

Comment: Bingo. I think I see the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1398/discussion-between-rilindo-and-stevether)

Answer (score 2):

Run `named` in the foreground so that it prints it's messages to stdout

```
/usr/sbin/named -f
```

If that doesn't give you sufficient information increase the debug level

```
/usr/sbin/named -f -d n
```

where n >=1 and increasing n produces more output.

Comment: Neither produced any output.

Comment: if you're running chroot, try starting named in the foreground like this:  /usr/sbin/named -u named -t /var/named/chroot -g

Comment: @anastrophe http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wD4HRBXp

Comment: So, it appears as if you don't have /etc/named.conf softlinked to your chrooted environment. In mine, which is pretty much a default install, /etc/named.conf is a softlink to /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf, as well with a softlink for the directory /etc/named.d to /var/named/chroot/etc/named.d .